# Running query against DMVs for Query Stats and Execution Plans joined to sys.databases

Tags: sql-server, performance, execution-plan, dmv, query-performance

I originally posted this as a different question in Twitter #sqlhelp, but wanted to post it here differently.

I'm trying to create a job that tracks worst performing statements for various statistics such as reads, writes, CPU, execution count, etc. using the DMVs *dm_exec_query_stats*, *dm_exec_cached_plans*, and *dm_exec_sql_text*, and originally *sys.databases*.

What happened was that this query would sometimes, and not all the time, take over 8 minutes to run on a busy server, but as soon as I removed the join to *sys.databases*, took only 9 seconds.  Most of this duration was CPU time, with very little waits, no blocking, no scans, only 13406 logical reads, and 1562 lob reads.

So what I want to know, is **why the huge performance hit from joining to sys.databases**?  And why is it inconsistent?

What happened was that when I ran the following test query, it would take over 8 minutes sometimes for no apparent reason, and other times complete in under 11 seconds.

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @snapshot_timeoffset AS datetimeoffset(3) = CAST(SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() AS datetimeoffset(3));

SELECT
    @snapshot_timeoffset AS [snapshot_timeoffset]
    ,db.name AS [database_name]  
    ,OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(st.objectid, st.dbid) [schema_name] 
    ,OBJECT_NAME(st.objectid, st.dbid) [object_name]   
    ,cp.objtype
    ,cp.usecounts
    ,cp.refcounts
    -- find the offset of the actual statement being executed
    ,SUBSTRING(st.text, 
            CASE
                WHEN qs.statement_start_offset = 0 OR qs.statement_start_offset IS NULL THEN 1  
                ELSE qs.statement_start_offset/2 + 1
            END, 
            CASE 
                WHEN qs.statement_end_offset = 0 OR qs.statement_end_offset = -1 OR qs.statement_end_offset IS NULL THEN LEN(st.text)  
                ELSE qs.statement_end_offset/2 
            END - 
            CASE
                WHEN qs.statement_start_offset = 0 OR qs.statement_start_offset IS NULL THEN 1  
                ELSE qs.statement_start_offset/2
            END + 1 
        ) AS [statement]  
    ,qs.execution_count
    ,qs.total_logical_reads
    ,qs.last_logical_reads
    ,qs.min_logical_reads
    ,qs.max_logical_reads
    ,qs.total_logical_writes
    ,qs.last_logical_writes
    ,qs.min_logical_writes
    ,qs.max_logical_writes
    ,qs.total_physical_reads
    ,qs.last_physical_reads
    ,qs.min_physical_reads
    ,qs.max_physical_reads
    ,qs.total_worker_time
    ,qs.last_worker_time
    ,qs.min_worker_time
    ,qs.max_worker_time
    ,qs.total_clr_time
    ,qs.last_clr_time
    ,qs.min_clr_time
    ,qs.max_clr_time
    ,qs.total_elapsed_time
    ,qs.last_elapsed_time
    ,qs.min_elapsed_time
    ,qs.max_elapsed_time
    ,qs.total_rows
    ,qs.last_rows
    ,qs.min_rows
    ,qs.max_rows
    ,qs.last_execution_time
    ,qs.creation_time
    ,qs.sql_handle
    ,qs.plan_handle
    ,qs.statement_start_offset
    ,qs.statement_end_offset
INTO #QueryStats
FROM master.sys.dm_exec_query_stats qs   
INNER JOIN  master.sys.dm_exec_cached_plans cp 
ON qs.plan_handle = cp.plan_handle 
CROSS APPLY  master.sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.plan_handle) st 
INNER JOIN  master.sys.databases db
ON st.dbid = db.database_id;
```

[image: Bad Plan]

By chance, I decided to remove the inner join to *sys.databases* and replace the lookup of the database name with the `DB_NAME()` function instead, and now it runs consistently in 9 seconds:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @snapshot_timeoffset AS datetimeoffset(3) = CAST(SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() AS datetimeoffset(3));

SELECT
    @snapshot_timeoffset AS [snapshot_timeoffset]
    ,DB_NAME(st.dbid) AS [database_name]  
    ,OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(st.objectid, st.dbid) [schema_name] 
    ,OBJECT_NAME(st.objectid, st.dbid) [object_name]   
    ,cp.objtype
    ,cp.usecounts
    ,cp.refcounts
    -- find the offset of the actual statement being executed
    ,SUBSTRING(st.text, 
            CASE
                WHEN qs.statement_start_offset = 0 OR qs.statement_start_offset IS NULL THEN 1  
                ELSE qs.statement_start_offset/2 + 1
            END, 
            CASE 
                WHEN qs.statement_end_offset = 0 OR qs.statement_end_offset = -1 OR qs.statement_end_offset IS NULL THEN LEN(st.text)  
                ELSE qs.statement_end_offset/2 
            END - 
            CASE
                WHEN qs.statement_start_offset = 0 OR qs.statement_start_offset IS NULL THEN 1  
                ELSE qs.statement_start_offset/2
            END + 1 
        ) AS [statement]  
    ,qs.execution_count
    ,qs.total_logical_reads
    ,qs.last_logical_reads
    ,qs.min_logical_reads
    ,qs.max_logical_reads
    ,qs.total_logical_writes
    ,qs.last_logical_writes
    ,qs.min_logical_writes
    ,qs.max_logical_writes
    ,qs.total_physical_reads
    ,qs.last_physical_reads
    ,qs.min_physical_reads
    ,qs.max_physical_reads
    ,qs.total_worker_time
    ,qs.last_worker_time
    ,qs.min_worker_time
    ,qs.max_worker_time
    ,qs.total_clr_time
    ,qs.last_clr_time
    ,qs.min_clr_time
    ,qs.max_clr_time
    ,qs.total_elapsed_time
    ,qs.last_elapsed_time
    ,qs.min_elapsed_time
    ,qs.max_elapsed_time
    ,qs.total_rows
    ,qs.last_rows
    ,qs.min_rows
    ,qs.max_rows
    ,qs.last_execution_time
    ,qs.creation_time
    ,qs.sql_handle
    ,qs.plan_handle
    ,qs.statement_start_offset
    ,qs.statement_end_offset
INTO #QueryStats
FROM master.sys.dm_exec_query_stats qs   
INNER JOIN  master.sys.dm_exec_cached_plans cp 
ON qs.plan_handle = cp.plan_handle 
CROSS APPLY  master.sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.plan_handle) st;
```

[image]

NOTE: the Table Valued Function `[SYSDMEXECCACHEDPLANS]` had Estimated CPU Cost 0.0522562, Estimated Number of Rows 52256 and Actual Number of Rows 52251 in the good plan.  However in the previous plan, the same function now has  **Actual Number of Rows 327605402**, which is a huge discrepancy.

I ran Paul Randal's [Extended Event Session](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/capturing-wait-stats-for-a-single-operation/) which traces wait types for a specific session on his suggestion and got the following output:

```
Wait Type            Count Total Wait (ms)  Resource Wait (ms)  Signal Wait (ms)
NETWORK_IO            4807            1119                1119                0
CXPACKET              9449             649                 620               29
SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD 119763             370                   0              370
SLEEP_TASK           11212               2                   0                2
LATCH_EX               782               1                   1                0
LATCH_SH                 2               0                   0                0
LCK_M_S                  4               0                   0                0
EXECSYNC                 3               0                   0                0
PAGEIOLATCH_EX           4               0                   0                0
PAGELATCH_EX             1               0                   0                0
PAGELATCH_SH             7               0                   0                0
PAGELATCH_UP            55               0                   0                0
```

Note that there is very little wait, yet CPU time almost matched the duration.  Paul mentioned this could be spinlock contention, however we are running on SQL 2014 SP1 CU2 and the bug https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/kb/3026083 was fixed already in SP1.  As well, not seeing anything jump out on system_health.xel.

A query of *sys.databases* by itself is always quite fast.

Comment: Also as you are on 2014, can you run the slow query with actual execution plan enabled - and once it's been going for a while have a look at `sys.dm_exec_query_profiles` for the busy operator(s) by cpu_time_ms

Answer (score 10):

> ...why the huge performance hit from joining to sys.databases? And why is it inconsistent?

There's nothing special about joining to *sys.databases*. The optimizer happens to choose a plan that is inefficient for the first query. Specifically, in this area of the plan:

[image: Plan fragment]

...the optimizer chooses a nested loops join to `SYSDMEXECCACHEDPLANS`, presumably based on an expectation of a very small number of driving rows on the outer input to the join (from the merge join). The optimizer introduces a table spool to reduce the processing cost of any duplicate values on the outer input to the nested loops join, but this is unlikely to be terribly effective - a hash join would have been "better".

> ..the same function now has Actual Number of Rows 327605402, which is a huge discrepancy.

This is a common mistake when reading execution plans in SSMS (SQL Sentry's [Plan Explorer](http://www.sqlsentry.com/products/plan-explorer/sql-server-query-view) does not suffer from this problem). In SSMS, the estimated number of rows on the inner side of a nested loops join is shown *per iteration*, whereas the actual number of rows is shown over *all iterations*. This is the result of a ["questionable design decision"](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback/Details/743480).

The **root cause** of the poor performance is therefore most likely simply that the complete set of all cached plans is scanned rather more times than the optimizer expected. Scanning the whole cache **6269 times** will be slow (unless the cache is tiny at the time).

Cardinality estimation errors do not just occur with user tables, so there is nothing too surprising about this. Don't blame it on *sys.databases* specifically. It is quite common for "an extra join" or "slight change to an predicate" to have a dramatic effect on plan selection.

You have fewer options than usual to help the optimizer with queries against system tables, views, and functions. For the *expert* analyst, hints may be the appropriate solution. In other cases, breaking the query up into more than one step may be best. In your case, simply replacing the "extra join" with a metadata function seems to be adequate, on the basis on the information provided.

Answer (score 8):

The SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD accumulation is just like I suggested on #sqlhelp. Each of those equates to 4ms of CPU time for the query, and they always show zero resource wait time, as there is no resource wait involved (thread yields the processor and goes directly to the bottom of the Runnable Queue on the scheduler).

So - this query was churning through CPU without needing any other resources.

This was also not anything to do with spinlocks, as they don't show up as a specific wait type (common misconception that SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD = spinlocks). I suggested that when you said there weren't any waits accruing.

When it runs slowly, does it return noticeably more rows than when it runs quickly?